# C++ Array of Lists of Objects

Tags: c++, arrays, list, templates, object

I have a class `KeyValuePair`

```
template <typename T>
class KeyValuePair {
public:
    //Default constructor
    KeyValuePair() {}

    //Copy assignment operator
    KeyValuePair& operator=(const KeyValuePair& obj) {
        KeyValuePair temp;
        return temp;
    }

    //Copy constructor
    KeyValuePair(const KeyValuePair<T>& obj) {
        this->key = obj.key;
        this->value = obj.value;
    }

    //Move consturctor
    KeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<T>&& obj) {
        this->key = std::move(obj.key);
        this->value = std::move(obj.value);
    }

    //Constructor to copy L-values
    KeyValuePair(const string& key, const T& value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
    }

    //Constructor to move R-values
    KeyValuePair(const string& key, T&& value) {

        this->key = key;
        this->value = std::move(value);
    }

    string key;
    T value;
};
```

I am trying to make an array of lists of `KeyValuePairs`.

```
list<KeyValuePair<string, T>> *arr = new list<KeyValuePair<string, T>>[10000]
```

When I try to make the array of lists I get two errors:

> `KeyValuePair`: too many template arguments
>
> `KeyValuePair`: unspecialized class template can't be used as a
>   template argument for template parameter `_Ty`, expected a real type.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: `KeyValuePair` needs only one template parameter. Instead of `KeyValuePair<string, T>`, use `KeyValuePair<T>`.

Comment: Use `std::vector`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> template <typename T>
> class KeyValuePair {
> /*...*/
> ```

The declaration of `KeyValuePair` only takes one template argument. If you're expecting it to take two, you need to write it something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class KeyValuePair {
/*...*/
```

Or, since your implementation seems to assume that all keys are `string`s, you could just remove the `string` use from the array instead:

```
list<KeyValuePair<T>> *arr = new list<KeyValuePair<T>>[10000];
```